# Does AsyncTask started by Service finish when Service stops?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I have a Service which does regular operations such as Bluetooth discovery and sending emails. Depending on the state, it starts different threads which does Bluetooth socket connection or send emails. I'm using AsyncTask to do email sending and it is working well at the moment.

The question I have is this: does AsyncTask I started from the Service finish when Service is stopped, or is the Service not stopped until AsyncTask completes? Under normal circumstances the Service is never 'stopped', but it can be stopped when the memory is low, or when the battery is low, or when the phone turns off. I need to resume the operation after the Service is stopped, and I'm wondering how to tell if AsyncTask has completed when the Service is stopped.

I have included a snapshot of my code.

```
public class ScheduledService extends Service {
    SendEmailAsyncTask emailTask;
    boolean emailSuccess;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId) {
        log.v("onStart()");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flag, startId);
        // do regular operations

        if (state == sendEmail) {
            emailTask = new SendEmailAsyncTask();
            emailTask.execute();
        }
    }


    class SendEmailAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // send email
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
            if (result) {
                createNotification("Email has been sent!");
                emailSuccess = true;
            } else {
                //try again
                emailSuccess = false;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the task won't stop  if its doing something and in between the service is stopped. Unless you call task's **cancel** method in service's **onDestroy's** implementation, it will be ended only once completed

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply! So the asynctask will not be stopped unless the phone is shut down? and is there any way of knowing whether the result of asynctask is successful or not?

Comment: the async task will complete if all the processing (**doInBackground**) is complete. Its not a keep-alive thread. In fact, it does heavy lifting on a separate thread, and once the processing is complete, it will finish itself automatically. You may know when the task is complete by observing its **onPostExecute** method. This method is called only once when the task is completed. For more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html